# Android: how to change navigation bar's color when softkeybord is displayed?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, navigationbar, soft-keyboard

With my app theme I show a colored navigation bar (the one at the bottom of the screen with back button) by using this attribute

```
 <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

When the soft keyboard comes up, the color turns into black. I'd like to keep my theme color.

Comment: I have the very same problem (Android 10), but kind of opposite: My `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">` works when the soft keyboard is shown. Did you solve your problem?